# Python 3 Beautiful Soup Data type incompatibility issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.3

Hello there stack community!

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to resolve since it looks like most of the help out there is for Python 2.7.

I want to pull a table from a webpage and then just get the linktext and not the whole anchor.

Here is the code:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re

```
url = 'http://www.craftcount.com/category.php?cat=5'

html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
alltables = soup.findAll("table")

## This bit captures the input from the previous sequence
results=[]
for link in alltables:
    rows = link.findAll('a')
## Find just the names
    top100 = re.findall(r">(.*?)<\/a>",rows)
print(top100)
```

When I run it, I get: **"TypeError: expected string or buffer"**

Up to the second to the last line, it does everything correctly (when I swap out 'print(top100)' for 'print(rows)').

As an example of the response I get:

```
<a href="http://www.etsy.com/shop.php?user_id=5323531"target="_blank">michellechangjewelry</a>
```

And I just need to get: 
michellechangjewelry

According to pythex.org, my (ir)regular expression should work, so I wanted to see if anyone out there knew how to do that. As an additional issue, it looks like most people like to go the other way, that is, from having the full   text and only wanting the URL part.

Finally, I'm using BeautifulSoup out of "convenience", but I'm not beholden to it if you can suggest a better package to narrow down the parsing to the linktext.

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup results are *not* strings; they are [`Tag` objects](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag), mostly.

Look for the *text* of the `<a>` tags, use the [`.string` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string):

```
for table in alltables:
    link = table.find('a')
    top100 = link.string
    print(top100)
```

This finds the *first* `<a>` link in a table. To find all text of all links:

```
for table in alltables:
    links = table.find_all('a')
    top100 = [link.string for link in links]
    print(top100)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.
Your explanation of the different data types is illustrative, as well. 
Cheers!